# Uncaught Reference Error: KrajeeDialog is not defined

Tags: jquery, yii2

Has anyone here gotten an error like this in the console when displaying the modal?

```
Uncaught Reference Error: KrajeeDialog is not defined
in eval (eval in globalEval (jquery.js:343:5), <anonymous>:3:33)
in evaluation (<anonymous>)
in Function.globalEval (jquery.js:343:5)
in domManip (jquery.js:5291:15)
in jQuery.fn.init.append (jquery.js:5431:10)
at jQuery.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.js:5525:18)
accessed (jquery.js:3614:8)
in jQuery.fn.init.html (jquery.js:5492:10)
in Object.success(js_general.js?v.1.176.3:380:39)
burnt (jquery.js:3187:31)
```

Here I use yii2 and jquery v2.2,
Previously it was running normally but in the last few days an error occurred after tracing because of Adblock, I tried turning off Adblock and it was running normally again, does anyone have another solution?